# Convert JSON string into list of object in Dart

Tags: json, string, flutter, serialization, dart

Im trying to convert a **string** into list of object in dart. The string look like this:

[What it looks like in my app - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0euoH.jpg)

[The JSON return - pastebin](https://pastebin.com/P4SXX8y8)

My class model:

```
class Post {
  GetDataResult getDataResult;

  Post({this.getDataResult});

  Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    getDataResult = json['GetDataResult'] != null
        ? new GetDataResult.fromJson(json['GetDataResult'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.getDataResult != null) {
      data['GetDataResult'] = this.getDataResult.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class GetDataResult {
  String retVal;

  GetDataResult({this.retVal});

  GetDataResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    retVal = json['RetVal'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['RetVal'] = this.retVal;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can convert your json array into list of object such as [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59960976/get-value-from-nested-json-array-and-check-if-it-is-empty-or-not-in-flutter/59962508#59962508)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. First I create a new class model:

```
class Profesi {
  String id;
  String description;
  String idPekerjaan;

  Profesi({this.id, this.description, this.idPekerjaan});

  Profesi from ({object: Map}) {
    var map = object;
    return Profesi(
      id: map['ID'] as String,
      description: map['Description'] as String,
      idPekerjaan: map['IDPekerjaan'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

in my postRequest method I prepare a variable to contain decoded json from my retVal:

```
List listJsonContent;
listJsonContent = json.decode(Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)).getDataResult.retVal);
```

Prepare a list of my new Profesi class and insert the object using add() method (here I insert just one: listJsonContent[0], you can insert all by iterate the list):

```
List<Profesi> profesi = List<Profesi>();
profesi.add(Profesi().from(object: listJsonContent[0]));
```

Try to print it to check:

```
print('${profesi[0].id}, ${profesi[0].idPekerjaan}, ${profesi[0].description}');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use gson, convert your string into list of object, gson.fromJson() method return what you want json format :

```
SomeObject[] yourJson = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), SomeObject[].class);
```

Please try above can, if you still facing issues share your error.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the Json To String.
For Example,

class sample {String name}
print(sample.name.toString());

Answer (score -1):

Use this link to create the Dart Object from Json.

Visit https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ this!

Comment: No. I need to convert the string value from JSON object. I already made the class model.